# How can I test my heatsink?

Tags: cpu, heatsink

Is there any way I can heat up my CPU and see if the heatsink works?

Answer (score 4):

Use a benchmark program such as [3DMark](http://www.futuremark.com/benchmarks/) or a “burn-in” utility such as [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft.htm).

If you want to have your CPU do something more productive while under a heavy load, use a distributed program like [BOINC](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/) or [Folding@home](http://folding.stanford.edu/) to have the CPU cycles put towards calculating things for finding cures to diseases, searching for extra-terrestrials, etc.

To keep an eye on the temps, use a monitoring program like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php).

Comment: +1 For being the FGIW, but you improved your answer providing some alternatives. If you are a mathematician, it is productive towards discovering the distribution of the prime numbers...

Comment: Prime95 for the win~!

Comment: >>>>>>>>>> FGIW?

Comment: @Linker3000 Fastest Gun in the West (even if it's just by 3 seconds)

Answer (score 2):

**If you can read this answer, it probably works.**

If you want to see how good it works, use software like [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) (°C) and [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft.htm) (stability test).

It's important that you monitor the temperature, you don't want to damage your equipment...

[image]